# How to duplicate a DataGridview column to particular index position - C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview which has 4 number of columns(A,B,C,D). The condition is sometimes the opeartor may need to duplicate column D with a different column name(at particular index position) but with exactly the same contents(for example column header text = 'copy of D'). I have tried the below code.

```
int lastcolidx = dataGridView3.Columns["SIGNAL TYPE"].Index;
dataGridView3.Columns.Add(dataGridView3.Columns[lastcolidx].Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
```

But this just adding the new empty column at the last position of the datagridview also the original column contents are not copied to new duplicated column. Please help me on how to do this

Comment: i would recommend you to dublicate the column in your DataSource. Then create new GridColumn as you described and bound the new column in DataSource to it.

Comment: Which type is your DataSource? DataTable or List<T> or sth?

Comment: my datasource is of List type

Comment: look my answer :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you did the column part but missed the row part. Column is like the UI (user interface, ie. room of your data), row is like the data itself. That why the newly added column is blank. you just need to fill the data rows (or cells of the new column).

A sample code for you:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("a", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("b", typeof(int));

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1); dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "sdfs", 23 });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "adbc", 5 });

        //The following part does the copying
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("c", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) dr.SetField<int>("c", dr.Field<int>("b"));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: is there a single statement to clone entire row data?/ I know we can do as datagridview3.rows[0].cells[1].value = datagridview3.rows[0].cells[1].value; i don't want to code like this for every cell data

Comment: for eg, in excel we can copy entire column A and paste in column B. i want to do the same function programatically with my datagridview

Comment: I have updated a sample code above. There should be no one-statement solution for your problem. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You say your DataSource is of List. So you could use an extra Property. This would be the easiest way i think. For example:

This is your Type:

```
public class MyClass
{
   string A {get;set;}
   string B {get;set;}
   string C {get;set;}
}
```

Add a new Property to this type:

```
public class MyClass
{
   string A {get;set;}
   string B {get;set;}
   string C {get;set;}
   string D { get{return C;}}
}
```

Now you always have a column D which looks like C. Via Visible=true/false you can show or unshow this column. I'm a fan of handling all data based stuff in the DataSource and just use the dataGridView for showing this data.

Hope this helps. If you need further help because the user should edit the values of C and D differently, let me know ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebi.